# the_post_thumbnail() returns nothing even though has_post_thumbnail() returns true

Tags: customization, post-thumbnails

has_post_thumbnail seems to be working fine but the_post_thumbnail returns nothing.

here is my code:

```
if ($favorite_post_ids):
    foreach ($favorite_post_ids as $post_id) {
            $p = get_post($post_id);
            echo "<li>";
            echo "<a href='".get_permalink($post_id)."' title='". $p->post_title ."'>" . $p->post_title . "</a> ";
            wpfp_remove_favorite_link($post_id);
            if (has_post_thumbnail($post_id))
            {
                echo $post_id;
                the_post_thumbnail($post_id);
            }
            echo "</li>";
        }
```

Here is the sample output:

> ```
> * Post101 remove 101
> * Post97 remove 97
> * Post59 remove 59
> ```

Most of the code above is irrelevant, I just included it for clarity. I have echoed the $post_id to make sure that it is passing the if (has_post_thumbnail($post_id)), which it does but the_post_thumbnail fails silently. I tried echoing it too but that returns nothing either.

I have got post_thumbnails turned on in the theme:

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) { 
  add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ); 
}
```

**any ideas? thanks**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're passing an invalid argument to [the_post_thumbnail()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail).

Here's your code: `the_post_thumbnail($post_id);`

Here's what `the_post_thumbnail()` expects: `the_post_thumbnail( $size, $attr );`

The function is expecting a `$size` as the first argument. Since `$post_id` is not a valid `$size`, the function doesn't know what to output.

Comment: You could try `echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $id, $size, $attr );` http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail

Comment: thanks guys. shoulda looked up the code ref!
used this:
**echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, 'thumbnail' );**